# Save UItextfield on UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an iOS application that allow user to write text with custom fonts on images , there is save button , when press this button the text is save and burn on the image but it's not save correctly , the text drop down .. please see the screen shot :

[image]

The problem is in this code , but I don't how I can fix it , I want to save text on image without moving down or up .

this is my code .

*-(void)realSave{*

```
// Request to save the image to camera roll

for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) {

    if (view.tag>=MIN_TAG_TEXT_BUTTON && view.tag<MAX_TAG_TEXT_BUTTON) {
        NSLog(@"TAG:%d",view.tag);



        //add text to image at here
     if ([self.tempStr length] > 0) {
         CATextLayer *normalTextLayer = [self customCATextLayerwithTag:view.tag];
         [drawImage.layer addSublayer:normalTextLayer];
        // [drawImage setImage:[self burnLayerIntoImage:drawImage.layer withImage:drawImage.image]];
         //[normalTextLayer removeFromSuperlayer];




        }
        else{

            [drawImage setImage:[self burnTextIntoImage:view withImage:drawImage.image]];

     }
        [view removeFromSuperview];
        saveBacking.hidden=YES;//ongraph added
        saveLabel.hidden=YES;//ongraph added
        spinner.hidden=YES; //ongraph added
        [spinner stopAnimating]; //ongraph added
```

}

```
}

appDelegate.__is_saved_image = TRUE;//ongraph added
appDelegate.__saved_image = drawImage.image;//ongraph added
currentTagAddTextButton=MIN_TAG_TEXT_BUTTON;
//UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(drawImage.image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);//ongraph uncommented
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.yourView.bounds.size);
[self.yourView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *shareImage =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

shareImage is UIImage , you can share and save it .. hope it can help you.

Comment: Hello , thanks for your help this looks nice , but I have -(IBAction) and from that -(IBAction) I can share the image , so if I use ure method in the void , then how I can export this UIimage to my -(IBaction) ?

Answer (score 0):

@user1288377 try this

```
btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn1 setFrame:CGRectMake(367, 117, 97, 25)];
[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(saveImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btn1];

   -(void)saveImage{/*saveImageMethod*/}
```